# Secure micronaut rest api with social login such as Google and Facebook login

Tags: oauth-2.0, micronaut-security

Given that I have mobile app which integrated with Google and Facebook login, how do I use Google and Facebook authentication in the Micronaut REST API? In the future, the mobile app will allow user to register (create new account) besides social login.

Thanks for writing the following articles:

- https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-oauth2-oidc-google/guide/index.html
- https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-oauth2-cognito/guide/index.html

Both articles above mentioned "Micronaut extracts the JWT from the Cookie and validates the JWT signature with the remote Json Web Key Set..."

Currently, the mobile apps has the access token return from Facebook OAuth2 and Google OAuth2, can't I simply pass the access token as bearer token for authentication?

I believe I'm missing some dots here, please advise.

Appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I found the solution implemented in spring boot at https://github.com/amrkhaledccd/spring-boot-jwt-social-auth and it's article at https://medium.com/javarevisited/jwt-and-social-authentication-using-spring-boot-90e4faaa9204. But I yet to figure out how to implement it using Micronaut Security.